# Error with ReadFile and Overlapped

Tags: c++, c, buffer, readfile, overlapped-io

I have a problem with ReadFile and overlapped.

first I use ReadFile with overlapped with 0

```
ZeroMemory(&overlapped ,sizeof(OVERLAPPED));

hDevice = CreateFileW(zwpath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);

if(hDevice != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){

ret = ReadFile(hDevice, buff, 1024, &numerobyte, &overlapped);

}
```

with a for(), I can see the bytes using a printf()

```
 for (int n=0; n<sizeof(buff); n++)  
       {  
           printf("0x%02X ", buff[n]);  
       }
```

and now I have one variant with a large number

```
crbig = 322122547

    d1 = (DWORD*)crbig;
    overlapped.Offset = d1[1]; //22122547
    overlapped.OffsetHigh = d1[0];// 00000003
```

I need use ReafFile twice, this second time is using overlapped() with offset and highoffset values

```
    d1 = (DWORD*)&crbig;
overlapped.Offset = d1[1];
overlapped.OffsetHigh = d1[0];

ret = ReadFile(hDevice, buff, 1024, &numerobyte, &overlapped);
```

but the for() prints the same bytes that throws me the first ReadFile, I tried cleaning the buffer with memset() or use another buffer but always show me the same bytes

Supposedly Overlapped() says to ReadFile where should go, and read 1024 bytes, and save it in a buffer, but nothing happen, buffer has the same first bytes that overlapped() = 0

this is the complete code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    HANDLE hDevice;
    OVERLAPPED overlapped;
    DWORD crbig;
    BYTE buff[1024] = {0};
    DWORD numerobyte = 0, nbytes = 0;
    UINT32 ret;
    DWORD *d1;
    int offset1 = 11, offset2 = 13, offset3 = 30;
    long MFTCluster = 0, bytespercluster = 0, sectperclusters = 0, offet = 0;
    unsigned long mult = 0;

    ZeroMemory(&overlapped ,sizeof(OVERLAPPED));

    hDevice = CreateFileW(zwpath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);

    if(hDevice != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){

        ret = ReadFile(hDevice, buff, 1024, &numerobyte, &overlapped);

    }else
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if(ret == 0){


        ret = WaitForSingleObject(hDevice,INFINITE );

        switch (ret)
        {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:break;
        case WAIT_TIMEOUT:break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }


    if((int)buff[3] == 'N' && (int)buff[4] == 'T' && (int)buff[5] == 'F' && (int)buff[6] == 'S' ){
        printf("Volumen es formato NTFS\n\n\n");
    }

    bytespercluster = endianhextodec(buff, offset1);
    sectperclusters = endianhextodec(buff, offset2);
    MFTCluster = endianhextodec(buff, offset3);

    crbig = (sectperclusters * (bytespercluster * MFTCluster));

    d1 = (DWORD*)&crbig;
    overlapped.Offset = d1[1];
    overlapped.OffsetHigh = d1[0];

    ret = ReadFile(hDevice, buff, 1024, &numerobyte, &overlapped);

    if(ret == 0){


        ret = WaitForSingleObject(hDevice,INFINITE );

        switch (ret)
        {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    for (int n=0; n<sizeof(buff); n++)  
    {  
        printf("0x%02X ", buff[n]);  
    } 

    CloseHandle(hDevice);

    getchar();
}
```

VB.NET

```
Private Sub SetReadFileOffset(ByRef NO As System.Threading.NativeOverlapped, ByRef curBig As Int64)

        Dim lowoffset() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(curBig)
        Dim highoffset As Int32 = BitConverter.ToInt32(lowoffset, 0)
        Dim high As Int32
        Dim lastbytes(3) As Byte
        Array.Copy(lowoffset, 4, lastbytes, 0, 4)
        high = BitConverter.ToInt32(lastbytes, 0)
        NO.OffsetLow = highoffset
        NO.OffsetHigh = high
    End Sub

 SetReadFileOffset(NO, MFTCluster * SectperCluster * BytesPerSect)
        ret = ReadFile(Hnd, Buffer, 1024, nRead, NO)
        If ret = 0 Then
            ret = WaitForSingleObject(Hnd, INFINITE)
            Select Case ret
                Case WAIT_OBJECT_0
                Case Else
            End Select
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
```

Comment: It is not valid to poke the OVERLAPPED structure like this.  You must use SetFilePointer() like normal to seek to a particular position in the file.  Do read up on the subject in the MSDN library, you are not writing valid code in general.

Comment: I try to convert VB code to C code